# Prove ${x:d(x,p) < d(x,q)}$ is open in metric space $X$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

$X$ is a metric space and $p \neq q$ $\in X$. I want to prove that $E=$ $\{x:d(x,p) < d(x,q) \}$ is open in metric space $X$.

I think I can directly prove this by showing every point $x \in E$ is an interior point of $E$ thus by definition $E$ is open in $X$.

To show $x$ is an interior point of $E$, I take $r= d(x,q)$ from above for $N_r(x)$. Then 
$N_r(x) \subset E$.

Thus $x \in E$ is an interior point of $E$. Since I take an arbitrary $x \in E$, this proves $E$ is of interior point. Is this proof correct?

Comment: You're skipping over the formality of the set inclusion step. Why is $N_r(x) \subset E$?

Comment: since I take $r =d(x,q)$? By the given set $E$, I think $N_r(x) = E$.   $N_r(x) = \{x : d(x,p) < r \}$

Comment: Typically, how is it proved whether a set is a subset of another set?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Then let me ask a question differently. Am I doing correctly so far? except for the fact that I did not show $x \in N_r(x)$ also lies in $E$.

Comment: Once you do that step, the remainder of the proof will fall out directly from the definition of an interior point.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r = d(x,q)$ then $N_r(x)$ contains points arbitrarily close to $q$. In particular, $N_r(x)$ contains points not in $E$.

Try taking a smaller $r$.

Edit: Here's a specific example with more details:

Take your metric space to be $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. Suppose $p = 2$ and $q = 0$. Then, the set $E$ consists of the points $x$ with $|x - 0| > |x - 2|$, which is exactly the points $x > 1$. (Check this.)

So suppose I take the point $x = 1.5$ in $E$. Then, $d(x,q) = d(1.5, 0) = 1.5$ and look at $N_{1.5}(1.5)$, this consists of all points within distance $1.5$ of $x = 1.5$. So, in particular, $N_{1.5}(1.5)$ contains $y = 0.5$, because $|x - y| = |1.5 - 0.5| = 1 < 1.5$. But $y$ is not in $E$, so your claim that $N_r(x) \subset E$ is false.

This went wrong because your $r$ was chosen to be too large, so I could find points in $N_{r}(x)$ closer to $q$ than to $p$.

Comment: Why is that? By definition $N_r(x) = \{ x : d(x,p) < r \}$ I take $r = d(x,q)$ Thus $N_r=d(x,q)(x) = \{ x : d(x,p) < r=d(x,q) \} = E$ I still don't know what I am doing wrong. Can you let me know some more details?

Comment: I edited. You should also look at your definition of $N_r(x)$. I think it should be $N_r(x) = \{y:d(x,y) < r\}$.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thanks

Comment: I apologize, but I still do not understand how we would generalize this example to a general metric space. Specifically, what would be some 'r' that would work?